# The menu jumps a few pixels after the website loads

Tags: menus, themes

I'm using Divi theme and having some weird issue with how the elements load within my website.. You can see that in the attacehed link -http://pointgrab.gonras.com/ .
When you click on one of the menu items' you can see what im talking about.. Any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score -1):

I like to call that "Fix it with JavaScript" aka "[Fix it in post](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FixItInPost)". It happens when a someone can't do something with CSS so they resort to JS. On a slow-loading site, such as the one you linked, the time it takes to load the JS is long enough so that any corrections to the display are visible to the human eye.

You can either fix the underlying display issue in the CSS so the JS doesn't have to do anything, fix whatever is causing the site to load so slowly so that the change is imperceivable, or live with the momentary flicker.

Comment: Is there any tool where I can see where my bottleneck is?